# Web based web server management

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

Greetings,

I maintain a website for a small company who have a Windows 2003 server hosting a website from their office. I need to make some changes to the server however it does not have remote login enabled.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any web based software I could place on the machine so I could upload, create, modify and delete directories and files via a browser, the web server is IIS.

I'd like this approach as I'd like to avoid opening up remote login incase it gets exploited, there is sensitive material on the server. (I've mentioned getting a second computer but that doesnt make sense according to accounting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the free version of Hamachi, or what is now called "[LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/)"  will do it without any firewall configuration required.   It will create a highly encrypted tunnel that won't likely be exploited (especially if you use a long password greater than 12 chars).  There are also some open source Hamachi look-a-likes such as [P2PVPN](http://p2pvpn.org/) or [Wippien](http://www.wippien.com/) , and some others, including the difficult to configure [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/) .   Also, with the tunnel open you will be able to RDP to the machine , bypassing the firewall.

Comment: Here is the [list of alternative apps](http://serverfault.com/a/746572/100769) for F2F / P2PVPN.

Answer (score 1):

I've used WebDAV and FTP to manage content on remote web servers.

Comment: WebDAV doesn't require any additional ports open on the firewall other than port 80 which should already be open for access to the web site. Here's an article the details how to install and configure it in IIS6 on W2K3:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/WebDAV-IIS.html

Answer (score 0):

The best WebDAV/FTP option, IMHO , is "[Null FTP Server](http://www.vwsolutions.com/NullFTPServer/)" .   I wouldn't recommend it over the vpn tunnel option though because it requires, just as RDP does, an open port in the firewall.  Therefore, I dont expect this to be your answer since you imply a firewall blocks you.

Answer (score 0):

Secure FTP (SFTP) would probably work great for you if you just need to do file management.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol